# iOS widgets auto-refresh

Tags: ios, widgetkit

For testing purposes, I'm trying to refresh a widget every 30 sec with the following code.

```
// PWContent is the TimelineEntry object.
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<PWContent>) -> ()) {
        
        NSLog("PWTimelineProvider.getTimeline(in)")

        let currentDate: Date = Date.now
        let calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current
        
        // Display a random element from the array 
        let entry: PWContent = PWContent(date: currentDate, planet: PWCustomData.sPlanets.randomElement()!)

        NSLog("Current time = " + String(describing: currentDate))
        
        // Set refresh date to 30sec in the future. 
        let refreshDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: 30, to: currentDate)!
        NSLog("Refresh time = " + String(describing: refreshDate))
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(refreshDate))
        
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

But I get the following logs

```
PWTimelineProvider.getTimeline(in)
Current time = 2023-01-08 07:53:31 +0000
Refresh time = 2023-01-08 07:54:01 +0000
PWTimelineProvider.getTimeline(in)
Current time = 2023-01-08 07:58:31 +0000
Refresh time = 2023-01-08 07:59:01 +0000
PWTimelineProvider.getTimeline(in)
Current time = 2023-01-08 08:03:31 +0000
Refresh time = 2023-01-08 08:04:01 +0000
```

As shown in the above logs, the widget refreshes every 5 mins (The difference b/w two 'Current Time'). When checking the Widget in home screen, it doesn't update every 30 sec.

My understanding (which is not what's observed): Widget first updates itself at 7:53:31. When the time is 7:54:01, getTimeline function is invoked (since the refresh policy was set to 7:54:01 i.e. 30 sec later than the previous time) by iOS to request another timeline, which again provides only one entry at the current time (= 7:54:01) and the new refresh policy is set to 7:54:31, which is when getTimeline is invoked again to get the next timeline.

Reference: Provide Timeline Entries section in [this wiki](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date),

> WidgetKit imposes a minimum amount of time before it reloads a widget. Your timeline provider should create timeline entries that are at least about 5 minutes apart.

And that's why, despite setting up a refresh period of 30sec, it still refreshes after 5mins.

But, in the following getTimeline(),

```
// ISWContent is the TimelineEntry object.
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<ISWContent>) -> ()) {
        NSLog(ISW_TAG + "ISWTimelineProvider.getTimeline(in)")
        
        let increment: Int = 15
        var entries: [ISWContent] = []
        let currentDate = Date.now
        
        // Generate a timeline consisting of 4 entries 15 sec apart,
        // starting from the current date.
        
        NSLog(ISW_TAG + "Current time = " + String(describing: currentDate))
        for index in 0...3 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: (index * increment), to: currentDate)!
            NSLog(ISW_TAG + "incremental dates[%d] = " + String(describing: entryDate), index)
            let entry = ISWContent(date: entryDate, state: ISWCustomData.sIndianStates.randomElement()!)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
```

Widget is refreshed every 15secs and once the last timeline entry has expired, getTimeline is invoked immediately to provide the next timeline. The 5mins restriction doesn't apply here.

Anyway, according to documentation, whatever timeline we return, is only a request and may not be granted if the user rarely views the home screen containing the widget or the app.