# Widget Update UI Every Minutes SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget

I'm creating a widget that's shown as an analog clock. Unfortunately, I don't know how to update the widget every minutes.
Here the code I have tried!

```
func createTimeline(widget: MWidgetModel, config: INFancyWidgetExtensionIntent)->Timeline<WidgetEntry>{
    var entries: [WidgetEntry] = []
    let currentDate = Date()
    let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
    let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!
        for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: currentDate)!
        entries.append(WidgetEntry(date: entryDate, widget: widget, configuration: config))
    }
   
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
    return timeline
}
```

it's work but create a lot of entries causes widget is not able to load UI.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75083511/ios-widgets-auto-refresh#:~:text=WidgetKit%20imposes%20a%20minimum%20amount,it%20still%20refreshes%20after%205mins.) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank @Timmy but still delay 5 minutes to refresh

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
func createTimeline(widget: MWidgetModel, config: INFancyWidgetExtensionIntent) -> Timeline<WidgetEntry> {
    let currentDate = Date()
    
    // Calculate the next minute
    let nextMinute = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
    
    // Create a single entry for the next minute
    let entry = WidgetEntry(date: nextMinute, widget: widget, configuration: config)
    
    // Create a timeline with just one entry
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextMinute))
    return timeline
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's doesn't work